# keras compile with dataset and flexible loss/metrics

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm porting a bunch of code from `tf.estimator.Estimator` API to `tf.keras` using `tf.data.Dataset`s and I'm hoping to stay as close to the provided `compile`/`fit` as possible. I'm being frustrated by compile's `loss` and `metrics` args.

Essentially, I'd like to use a loss function which uses multiple outputs and labels in a non-additive way, i.e. I want to provide

```py
def custom_loss(all_labels, model_outputs):
    """
    Args:
        all_labels: all labels in the dataset, as a single tensor, tuple or dict
        model_outputs: all outputs of model as a single tensor, tuple or dict

    Returns:
        single loss tensor to be averaged.
    """"
    ...
```

I can't provide this to `compile` because as far as I'm aware it only supports weighted sums of per-output/label losses, and makes assumptions about the shape of each label based on the the corresponding model output. I can't create it separately and use `model.add_loss` because I never have explicit access to a labels tensor if I want to let `model.fit` handle dataset iteration. I've considered flattening/concatenating all outputs and labels together, but then I can't monitor multiple `metrics`.

I can write my own training loop using `model.train_on_batch`, but that forces me to replicate behaviour already implemented in `fit` such as dataset iteration, callbacks, validation, distribution strategies etc.

---

As an example, I'd like to replicate the following estimator.

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    outputs = get_outputs(features)  # dict
    loss = custom_loss(labels, outputs)
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss)
    eval_metrics_op = {
      'a_mean': tf.metrics.mean(outputs['a'])
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        loss=loss, train_op=train_op, mode=mode, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
estimator.train(dataset_fn)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: added estimator example